# Beaglebone black usb host current

Tags: usb, beaglebone-black, beagleboard

I'm using a Beaglebone black + BBVIEW 4.3 LCD Display + Datalogic Magellan 110i usb scanner. The scanner is connected to the usb host port but when I read a bar code the scanner goes down and then up again. The scanner datasheet says that during reading the current goes to a 400ma maximum so it should not be a problem to the USB host port. If I remove the LCD cape I have no power problems. The board is connected to an industrial adjustable power source 2.5A power source used for testing. Is the maximum current available in the USB host related to current for the LCD cape?

Comment: How are you powering the BeagleBone board — via the barrel connector or the USB B port? What are the specs of the power supply you're using? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was not a current problem but voltage. The power cable i used was a bit long so i had a voltage drop of around 0.5v. I changed the voltage at the source to 5.5V and everything is ok now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, it was not a current problem but voltage. The power cable i used was a bit long so i had a voltage drop of around 0.5v. I changed the voltage at the source to 5.5V and everything is ok now. Thanks – Rui Sebastião Nov 28 '14 at 10:22